# while loop breaks before it's supposed to, logic issue?

Tags: java, loops, logic

In the program I'm writing, I have a list of words, and for each word this method is supposed to run through an entire dictionary and compare the given word to the dictionary. For some reason, it only compares the first word, but continues to increment through the givenWordCounter without running it through the dictionary.

It must be something wrong with my logic but I don't know what it is. Below is the pseudocode that I came up with and also the code itself, do you see any huge mistake I am making?

pseudo code:

```
for each word in the givenWords list:
  while dictionaryCounter < dictionary.size():
    run word in givenWord list at givenWordCounter index through the dictionary
    increment thousandCounter by 1000
increment givenWordCounter by 1

program should loop through every word in givenWords list & for each givenWord 
loop through dictionary.prefix once. after dictionary.prefix loop is done move
on to next givenWord
```

and the code:

```
public static void runProgram(){
int givenWordCounter = 0; 
int thouCount = 1000;

while (givenWordCounter < givenWords.size()){
    while (thouCount < theDictionary.size()){

        Dictionary.prefix(givenWords.get(givenWordCounter), theDictionary, counter, thouCount);
        thouCount = thouCount + 1000;
    }
    givenWordCounter++;
 }
}
```

from my understanding of how I wrote the code it should work but i'm somehow making a big mistake, I guess?

**edit:**
I was asked to include the code called in the Dictionary class, here it is (required to be recursive by assignment):

```
 public static void prefix (String origWord, List<String> theDictionary, int beginFrom, int endAt){


            // if the words don't match recurse through this same method in order to move on to the next word
        if (beginFrom < theDictionary.size() && counter < endAt){   
          if ( origWord.charAt(0) != theDictionary.get(beginFrom).charAt(0) || origWord.length() != theDictionary.get(beginFrom).length()){

              counter = counter + 1;
              prefix(origWord, theDictionary, beginFrom+1, endAt);  
          }

          // if the words first letter and size match, send the word to prefixLetterChecker to check for the rest of the prefix.
          else{
              prefixLetterChecker(origWord, theDictionary.get(beginFrom), 1);
              counter = counter + 1;
              prefix(origWord, theDictionary, beginFrom+1, endAt);
          }
        }



     }
```

Comment: Can you give us some code of the `Dictionary` class ? Is this an `Iterable` ? You are making a bad use of while loops, for or foreach loops would be a hundred times better here

Comment: sure editing to include the prefix method from the Dictionary class that this code calls

Comment: @dici ok i updated it

Comment: Thanks, but the piece of code you added is not relevant here. I just wanted to know if it was implementing the `Iterable` interface

Comment: @dici ohhh i see i'm sorry, it doesn't

Comment: The prefix method seems to be bad design. Instead of calling a static method with a `List<String> dictionary` parameter, should not the `Dictionary` class hold a `List<String> words` attributes and define a non-static `prefix` method ? It would then be easy to make the class iterable by returning the iterator of `words`

Comment: @dici I should have said at the beginning, the assignment requires for us to use a recursive method in the prefix method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap (and slightly change) these two lines,

```
int thouCount = 1000;
while (givenWordCounter < givenWords.size()){
```

(should, I think, be)

```
while (givenWordCounter < givenWords.size()){
  int thouCount = 1000 + givenWordCounter; // <-- to offset givenWordCounter.
```

Because you need to reset the `thouCount` on each loop iteration.

Comment: hehe yeah I literally figured it out at the same time as you posted this, thank you!!!!

Comment: Even if it works this is not a good way to iterate through a list at all. You should use while loops only in case you don't know in advance the number of iterations.

Comment: @Dici Since the Java compiler and JIT will optimize away any difference in performance, *why* do you recommend against `while`?

Comment: @dici I don't know the exact number, the user inputs their own dictionary so it can be of any size

Comment: The dictionary does not change of size during the loop, so you definitely know the number of iterations.

Comment: @dici oh I see what you mean, ok

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured it out!!

The issue was that the "counter" was at the end of the size of the dictionary, all I needed to do was add a thing to put the counter back to zero after each run through the dictionary! d'oh. Should I delete this question?